# Get previous build result

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2

I want to emulate the original Jenkins behaviour of doing stuff (like sending out notifications) when builds become unstable / fail or become successful again.

For that I need to query the previous build status, which can be done like this:

```
currentBuild.rawBuild.getPreviousBuild()?.getResult().toString()
```

However, `rawBuild` is supposed to be a "dangerous" object and as thus blacklisted and [cannot be executed inside the Groovy sandbox](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28178).

Now, since I'm loading my Jenkins scripts from SCM, there is no way for me to deactivate the Groovy sandbox on a per-project level, but only for the whole Jenkins instance (i.e. [through this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Permissive+Script+Security+Plugin)), and this is certainly not something I want.

Is there any other way of determining the last build status of a job that conforms with the sandbox principles (and does not include hacks like querying the status via Jenkins' REST API) that I have missed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No need to access `rawBuild`, instead you can do the following without any special permissions:

```
currentBuild.getPreviousBuild().result
```

This will allow you to see the result of the previous build without needing to have any special privileges set by the Jenkins administrator.  It should be able to be run anywhere.

Global Variable Reference: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#global-variable-reference

And more specifically, in your own Jenkins: $*{YOUR_JENKINS_URL}/pipeline-syntax/globals#currentBuild*

More information: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/217591038-How-to-Iterate-Through-the-Last-Successful-Builds-in-Pipeline-Job

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. When your link goes dead, your answer becomes useless. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @Rob edited to add some context.  Not sure why the downvote?

Comment: I did not downvote and prefer to comment. There are 8000 to 10,000 questions asked every day. It could have been anyone but my problem with your answer was that there was no explanation for what it did. As stated in [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), Stack Overflow wants to be "a library of **detailed answers** to every question about programming."

Comment: @Rob no comment on the current state?  Still not up to standards?

Comment: Don't know what you mean. If it's about Jenkins, I wouldn't know.

Answer (score 5):

If you approve the method `getRawBuild` from **Manage Jenkins** > **In-process Script Approval** after you get `RejectedAccessException` on a build,
you can use the method from a next build even in the groovy sandbox.

Besides `getRawBuild`, you need to approve `getPreviousBuild` and `getResult` one by one after you get the exception against each method for your script.