# How to call Jenkins REST API without passing credentials using Java in already logged-in Jenkins?

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-api

I have used Jenkins REST API URL to get build status using Java (JAR). It is working successfully by passing user name and password to the API URL. I created a job in Jenkins and using that JAR file to get build status. But, my question is that why should the credential be passed again to API URL as I already logged-in in Jenkins to access the job? The API URL should be accessible without credentials. How to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

REST does not persist any session information:

> Relevant session data is sent to the receiver by the client in such a way that every packet of information transferred can be understood in isolation, without context information from previous packets in the session.

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Statelessness

That means, you must send the credentials with every call by design.

You can have a look at the Java API Client for Jenkins, but it uses the REST API under the hood as well I assume: https://github.com/jenkinsci/java-client-api

Comment: Thank you. For testing I hard coded username and password in java to call API URL. But for production, I need to get the logged-in user's password to pass. Planned to add a password parameter for the user to manually enter their password, but I have more than 100 project and need to configure in all. It's a time consuming task. any other method to achieve it.

Comment: What is the usecase exactly?

Comment: I created 100+ parameterized freestyle jobs in Jenkins & maintaining a single ANT build XML file for release process & working effectively in prod.I need to get previous build details & use in current build.For that,I am calling Jenkins API in java to get details by passing specific job name,build number,username and password & using JAR in ANT build.It is one time process & not required to change in 100+ job.But for password,it is required to touch all jobs' configuration it seems as I hard coded password in Java.I am trying to incorporate new requirement without disturbing current process.

Comment: Perhaps this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284904/get-previous-build-result